# Normalizing data in data frame with data from different data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm analyzing some federal data that is aggregated on a state-by-state basis.  The row labels are state names, column labels are the facet labels.  The cell values are the population counts.  This df looks like:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|                            f1     f2  |
| Alabama                    127    321 |
| Alaska                      84    12  |
| Arizona                    295    12  |
| Arkansas                    82    71  |
+---------------------------------------+
```

I have another data frame where the rows are also state names, but the single column is the population of that state.  This df looks like:

```
+--------------------------------+
|                          Counts|
| Alabama                    146 |
| Alaska                      89 |
| Arizona                    314 |
| Arkansas                    85 |
+--------------------------------+
```

I would like to divide every column in the first data frame by the values in the second data frame.  This normalizes state incidence data by population.

How can I accomplish this in pandas?  I'm experienced in python, but a pandas newbie, and can't figure it out.

TIA,
Travis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html#pandas.DataFrame.div) with `axis=0`:

```
>>> left
           f1   f2
Alabama   127  321
Alaska     84   12
Arizona   295   12
Arkansas   82   71
>>> right
          Counts
Alabama      146
Alaska        89
Arizona      314
Arkansas      85
>>> left.div(right['Counts'], axis=0)
             f1     f2
Alabama   0.870  2.199
Alaska    0.944  0.135
Arizona   0.939  0.038
Arkansas  0.965  0.835
```

note that this aligns the right hand side to the index of left hand side, so the result of below would be the same as above:

```
>>> left.div(right.loc[::-1, 'Counts'], axis=0)  # permute the indices
             f1     f2
Alabama   0.870  2.199
Alaska    0.944  0.135
Arizona   0.939  0.038
Arkansas  0.965  0.835
```